# In C++, is created vector or map in a function on stack or heap?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I just have a very simple question but I can not find it through google.

In C++, if we create a integer in a function, I believe it will be in stack. But if we create a vector or a map, for example,

```
vector<int> a
```

will it on stack or heap? I believe that's kind of class object(similar to the object created by "new" in java) so probably it should be on heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vector<int>` object itself is created in the storage of your choice: if you declare it as a local variable, that would be in the automatic storage.

However, the vector is usually represented as a pair of pointers; the *data* for that vector is allocated in the dynamic storage area.

Same goes for `std::map<K,V>`: the object goes wherever you put it (automatic, static, or dynamic memory, based on your declaration) while the data goes into the dynamic storage area.

Starting with C++11 you can use [`std::array<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) class for fixed-size collections. The data of this collection will go entirely in the storage where you put the collection itself. However, such collections are not resizable.

Comment: I a function, I just declare vector<int> a. That's it. So you mean it is in stack? Then can you tell me how I can declare it in the heap?

Comment: @HaoShen why would you declare it on the heap ? There is no need for you to bother.

Comment: @HaoShen The vector (usually, a pair of pointers pointing to the beginning and to the end of the dynamically allocated data) are on the stack; the bulk of the vector, i.e. its data, is in the heap.

Comment: @Johan No. I think if the vector is going to be very big, I definitely need it on heap. Stack is very small for each thread.

Comment: @HaoShen The stack footprint of the vector is tiny, and it remains the same regardless of the amount of data in the vector.

Comment: @HaoShen whatever the size of your data `vector` will always be the same size on your stack. It contains mostly a pointer to the dynamically allocated data. So no problem because this data is not on the stack.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hi,das, I just got a question. So if the function returns, the data would still stay in heap? If I know the address, I can still retrieve the data on the heap?

Comment: @HaoShen The data would remain in the dynamic storage until it is deallocated. C++ containers deallocate their dynamic memory in their destructors, so the data in the heap would be lost unless you transfer the ownership of that data to another container.

Answer (score 3):

The data for any dynamically sized object like that will be heap allocated. If it were on the stack it would risk an overflow and a program crash if it grew too large.

The object itself (i.e. the size of the dynamic array and the pointer to the data's location in memory) will likely be stored on the stack.

Comment: The vector itself is on the stack if declared as a local variable. The dynamic memory zone that is managed by the vector however is not on the stack.

Comment: I figured that is what the poster was asking about. I'll edit my answer however.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this will also be created on the stack.

Variables are only created on the heap when new or malloc is called.

The type doesnt really matter, what matters is how its created.

If you're trying to decide whether or not to create a varaible on the stack or dynamically (on the heap), you should consider the lifetime of the object. If you just need it during the scope that its created in, then create it on the stack. Otherwise create it dynamically.

Comment: A dynamic object like that will have to be heap allocated for it to be able to grow or shrink on its own.

Comment: @mebob, no. As stated in comment to your answer, `vector` itself is not dynamic. It contains a dynamically allocated memory zone.

Comment: My mistake, I was assuming the question was referring to the data and not the object data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the vector is stored both on the heap and on the stack. Meaning, the header is on the stack, but as you put elements into the vector, those are dynamically allocated, hence on the heap.